# Выбор всех книг у которых несколько авторов

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть три таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выбрать все книги у которых более одного автора и этих самых авторов тоже отобразить?
Пишу вот так:

```
SELECT authors.name, book.name_book
FROM authors 
INNER JOIN book_author ON authors.id_author = book_author.id_author 
INNER JOIN book ON book_author.id_book = book.id_book
WHERE book_author.id_book IN (
    SELECT book.id_book
    FROM book 
    INNER JOIN book_author ON book.id_book = book_author.id_book 
    INNER JOIN authors ON book_author.id_author = authors.id_author
    GROUP BY book_author.id_book
    HAVING COUNT(book_author.id_author) > 1
)
ORDER BY book_author.id_book
```

И оно работает, но что то мне подсказывает, что это все можно сделать проще и лучше. Как это сделать проще?

Comment: по крайней мере в подзапросе вам точно не нужен джойн, работайте только с таблицей связи, там есть все что надо

Comment: ну это ладно, это мелочи. Он просто остался от предыдущего запроса и пропустил его

Comment: Ну это не мелочи, это две лишние таблицы в запросе. а в остальном ничего улучшать

Comment: Если на уровне структуры (уникальным индексом) не поддержан контроль отсутствия дубликатов, условие пост-отбора подзапроса следует сформировать как `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_author)`

Comment: @Mike да я понимаю это, просто это я пропустил при копировании запроса, поэтому и говорю что это не суть

Comment: @Akina извиняюсь, отсутствие дубликатов в какой таблице? book_author? И вопрос тогда не по теме. Как это реализовать? Триггером только? при добавлении проверять есть или нет? Или это как то проще можно сделать?

Comment: @NoName Да, именно в связующей таблице. А лечится это простым созданием уникального индекса на пару полей (id_book,id_author) - ну или в обратном порядке, смотря что полезнее для производительности.

Comment: а почему выбрать из таблицы автор, а не из таблицы книга_автор?